# Want to learn automation testing using geb in android?

Tags: android, groovy, automation, spock, geb

I know geb is browser automation solution but I want to implement geb in android.

Can any one help me with some references or any sample code.

It would be nice if geb implementation using groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Using Geb takes that to the next level, by combining the power of WebDriver with the power of JQuery and Groovy. For mobile web applications, we can use all this and not simply automate testing in Firefox, or in Firefox with a mobile user agent, but on the devices themselves! Currently, Android and iOS devices are supported
[Here a reference](http://zachlendon.github.io/blog/2012/05/15/improving-mobile-capabilities-of-geb-pages-and-spock-specifications/)